# Ubuntu (12.04 LTS) and SteelSeries Apex Gaming Keyboard

Tags: 12.04, keyboard

Has anyone successfully gotten the macro buttons working with the SteelSeries Apex Gaming keyboard (MX1-MX10)?

Answer (score 0):

This is the answer I gave at a similar question ( [Get macro keys on steelseries apex (keybord) to work](https://askubuntu.com/questions/366446/get-macro-keys-on-steelseries-apex-keybord-to-work/376080#376080) ):

"I have one and I wasn't able to find anything useful to use them nor change the colors. But I have the skills to develop a linux app to control the keyboard. The only thing I need is the information regarding the comunication method and the protocol specs, and I have already contacted SteelSeries support asking for that. I'll let you know if there are any news."

Comment: any news on this?