# Get macro keys on steelseries apex (keybord) to work

Tags: keyboard, settings

I just got a new keyboard but none of the macro keys work when going into the keymapping of games they don't see the macro keys. I saw this app "Xmacro" but I couldn't get it to work. Is it possible to set macro keys without "Steelseries engine" (mac, windows)?

Comment: Anybody coming across this may find the following project on GitHub useful. [https://github.com/tuxmark5/ApexCtl](https://github.com/tuxmark5/ApexCtl) Haven't tried it yet, keyboard is still in the box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got everything working with [ApexCtl](https://github.com/tuxmark5/ApexCtl) following the instructions in the readme file and following [this](https://github.com/tuxmark5/ApexCtl/issues/29) to set up the keys right

Answer (score 0):

Checking their site and paging down once, at the bottom of the list titled "APEX VS. APEX [RAW]" I noticed this:

> Linux support is limited to basic HID Keyboard, Windows Key toggling, and illumination brightness control.

To me, this means macro keys will not work as they have no support outside of Windows and OSX.

[source](http://steelseries.com/products/keyboards/steelseries-apex-gaming-keyboard)

Comment: I did see this but I was wondering if there was any manual way to get the system to recognise the extra keys.